# Ember.js - get the model data of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a DOM element and want to get the data model that it is bound to.

This has to be done outside of any ember controller / component. All I have to work with is the DOM element and the global Ember variable (because this piece of code runs from an externally loaded script file).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done (not out of the box anyway). There is no relationship between DOM elements and models. The best way I could think of doing this would be to bind the ID of the model to and attribute on a particular DOM item. For example:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    model: null,
    attributeBindings: ['data-model-id'],
    'data-model-id': function() {
        return this.get('model.typeKey') + ':' + this.get('model.id');
    }.property('model.{typeKey,id}');
});
```

Then you'd get an element in the DOM like this:

```
<div id="ember189" data-model-id="user:86">...</div>
```

But this only works if your HTML is written such that each model gets its own DOM element. And you'd still have to access private API to get the store via `App.__container__.lookup()`.

Unless you feel like you have a *really* good reason to do something like this, I would avoid it.